# Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CompilerSystemProperties'

Tags: android, kotlin

I keep getting this error in Android Studio. I think I accidentally deleted a Gradle script file. Reinstalling Android Studio and starting a new project does nothing.

> Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CompilerSystemProperties'.

> This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Any help on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.